# rename files using each file as a param on ubuntu command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, sed

I'd like to rename these html files to start with "shopping-cart" as I didn't realize there will be several files in this course. So `chapter-2.html` goes to `shopping-cart-chapter-2.html`, and so on, with folders and `style.css` being ignored.

```
cchilders:~/tutorials/knockoutjs/knockout-for-students-book (master) 
$ ls
chapter-2-page-19.html  chapter-3.html      chapter-5.html      style.css
chapter-2.html      chapter-4.html      knockoutjs_succinctly
```

I need to get each file in this folder as an array instead of string, evaluate if each file ends in `.html`, then rename it like

```
mv chapter-4.html shopping-cart-chapter-4.html
```

by using the filename and "shopping-cart" + the filename

This is a common thing I need to do from command line for a course I need to write where filenames are significant (becoming titles), and I normally can't figure out how to do it in bash. What are the steps on command line, like the proper program `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, etc? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a loop:

```
cd ~/tutorials/knockoutjs/knockout-for-students-book
for f in *.html; do
  mv "$f" "chopping-chart-$f"
done
```